# Qt Creator Debug works but release cannot be compiled

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have some trouble to generate a release folder in QtCreator 4.7.2 based on Qt 5.11.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit). My program runs just fine in the debug version, but when I change the build to the release version, I get compiler errors.

I use the QCustomPlot library inside my application, and somehow in the release build it does not like

```
integerPart > 0 ? QString::number(integerPart)+QLatin1String(" ") : QLatin1String("")
```

which throws me a **C2446: ':': no conversion from 'QLatin1String' to 'QStringBuilder'**

So I replaced the line for testing with

```
integerPart > 0 ? "" : ""
```

and so the compiler throws no more errors, but now I get a **LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'**

I tried to clean the build and run qmake, but the linker error does not disappear. Any Ideas what could cause this problems? I only switched from debug to release.

**Edit:**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-11-09T09:59:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = PlotterApp
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += QT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

QT += serialport

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    serialporthandler.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \
    parameterobject.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    serialporthandler.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    parameterobject.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Why the `QLatin1String` instead of just `" "`? `QString` has an [`operator+`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-2b-1) for `const char*`

Comment: Well, I did not write that, this is part of the QCustomPlot library.

Comment: Hm, here is [blog post about QStringBuilder](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/13/string-concatenation-with-qstringbuilder/), maybe this is relevant. Could `QT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER` be defined in release only? Then the `operator +` would return `QString` in debug and `QStringBuilder` in release builds, if I understood this correctly. On the other hand, this post is about Qt4, don't know if it still applies.

Comment: Looks like the compiler is trying to convert the second `QLatin1String("")` into `QStringBuilder`. With a ternary expression, both expressions before and after the colon need to be the same type. Have you tried replacing it with `integerPart > 0 ? QString::number(integerPart) + QString("") : QString("")`?

Comment: Ok, the integerPart > 0 ? QString::number(integerPart) + QString("") : QString("") part worked. Now There is still this Linker Error, but only in the relase. There is not stated what is wrong with the linker script, I posted the scrupt above in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86

and copy **rc.exe** and **rcdll.dll** to the following folder

**X64**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64

**X86**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

Comment: Hmm ok, I did this, but still I have the same error.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft What is your build option? X64 release or X86 release?

Comment: Hi 张铁男, it's X86 release

Comment: @HansPeterLoft Update the answer.